# Como que gera coluna no html

Tags: javascript, html

Eu queria rodar um script pra poder calcular um juro que chama sac.
Não vou estender como isso funciona, o que queria é alguém ajudasse bem breve como faço um script pra gerar colunas, só isso.

```
</head>

<body>
    <form name="calculator_sac" class="vertical">
        <div>
            <label>
                Valor:
                <input autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" name="valor_total" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                Número de meses:
                <input autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" name="prazo" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                Taxa de Juros (%) ao ano:
                <input autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" size="10" name="taxa" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                Constante amortização mensal:
                <input autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" size="10" name="amortizacao_extra"
                    value="0" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
        <button onclick="calculaTabela()">calcular</button>
    </div>

    <div id="sac_result"></div>
</html>
```

Tô começando programar, aí quem tiver paciência...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para gerar a tabela basta inclui-la com innerHTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Tabuada" min="1" max="100">
        <input type="number" placeholder="vezes" min="1" max="100">
        <button onclick="gerarTabuada()">Gerar tabuada</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <table id="tabela"></table>
    </div>

    <script>
        function gerarTabuada() {
            // Pegar o valor das inputs ao executar essa função
            const tabuada = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
            const vezes = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value);
            // Definir a constante de nome 'tabela' para a id 'tabela' no documento html
            const tabela = document.getElementById('tabela');

            // Limpar toda escrita dentro da tabela
            tabela.innerHTML = '';

            // Adicionar título às colunas
            tabela.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                    <th>Tabuado do ${tabuada}</th>
                    <th>Resultado</th>
                </tr>`;

            // Excutar esse código o número de vezes que está no valor da input 'vezes' 
            for (i = 0; i < vezes + 1; i++) {
                // Fazer o cálculo entre o valor da 'tabuada' e o numero da linha atual 'i'
                let resultado = tabuada * i; 
                // Adicionar linhas à tabela com os valores das variaveis
                tabela.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${tabuada} x ${i} = </td>
                        <td>${resultado}</td>
                    </tr>`;
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
```